# How to bind string (update that string when change him) from viewmodel with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to implement MVVM arquitecture  and i am trying to bind two string variables from my model but I cannot

I have this model and viewmodel:

```
data class LoginModel(var correo:String = "", val password:String = "")

class LoginViewModel:ViewModel() {
    var model by mutableStateOf(LoginModel())

    fun setEmail(text:String){
        model.correo = text
    }
}
```

And i have this @Composable function:

```
@Composable
fun LoginPage(navController: NavController,viewModel: LoginViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val paddingBox=30.dp //padding for box
    BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(paddingBox)) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {

                            Row(modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp))) {
                            //var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
                            OutlinedTextField(
                                value = viewModel.model.correo,
                                onValueChange = {viewModel.setEmail(it)},
                                modifier= Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .background(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color.White),
                                shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 20),
                                trailingIcon = {
                                    Icon(imageVector= Icons.Filled.Email,"correo")
                                },
                                singleLine = true)
                        }

                      
            //container of elements
        }
    }
}
```

but UI is not being updated. I write in emulator but nothing is changed. why ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your viewmodel contains `LoginModel`'s object as the mutable state. But inside the `setEmail` method, you are just updating the underlying value of that mutable state's object. The underlying change will not be considered by the compose compiler as the object is still the same.

You can do something like this,

Change the `correo` to `val` from `var`.

```
data class LoginModel(val correo: String = "", val password: String = "")
```

And the viewmodel

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var model by mutableStateOf(LoginModel())

    fun setEmail(text: String) {
        model = model.copy(correo = text)
    }
}
```

If you update the object itself, it will reflect in UI as this will make the recomposition.

Comment: Consider reading https://dev.to/zachklipp/two-mutables-dont-make-a-right-2kgp which goes into more depth this topic.